# Why can't I get access to environment variables from Python through Apache server?

Tags: python, apache

I have a Flask web app that I'm trying to run on webfaction. The application runs fine through Gunicorn and the test server, but I can't get it to work with Apache.

I've narrowed it down to the lack of access to environment variables. If I run the app with Gunicorn, the environment variables are correct and the app works correctly. If I run the app with Apache, I can't access the environment variables.

Note: the environment variables are set correctly and exported correctly, so that's not where the issue lies. Again, it works perfectly, only not with Apache.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: You mean an apache reverse proxy? How are you running it?

Comment: standard webfaction setup with mod_wsgi; see https://community.webfaction.com/questions/12718/installing-flask (answer with 5 upvotes)